# Homemorphism between fundamental polygon and $ℝP^{2}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that the square where the opposite edges are glued together in the inverse direction
is homemorphic to the real projective plane $ℝP^{2}$. I proofed that $ℝP^{2}$ is homemorphic to $S^²/\tilde{}$ with $x\tilde{}(-x)$, so finding a Homeomorphism to $S^2/\tilde{}$ would also be enough. My problem is that I don't really know where to start because I can't even imagine how the square would look after being glued together.

[image: fundamental polygon]

Comment: You can think to the map that sends $BA$ to the equator and the interior of the square to a hemisphere...

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Is it possible to write this down explicitely?

Comment: I think that what you need can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365920/prove-a-square-is-homeomorphic-to-a-circle

Comment: @Dario That's square to circle. What I was having trouble with was square to hemisphere or circle to hemisphere, but I just realized that I can just vertically project the points on the hemisphere, so I think I got it know. Thanks for your help.