# How to show these two maps are continuous and inverse each other?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm having troubles in showing the following: consider the circle and the square:

$$S^1 = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; x^2+y^2 = 1\} \qquad \qquad Q = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert = 1\}$$

They are topologically identical. Consider the maps

$$f: S^1 \to Q, \qquad \qquad f(x, y) = \left( \frac{x}{\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert}, \frac{y}{\vert x \vert + \vert y \vert}\right)$$

$$g: Q \to S^1, \qquad \qquad g(x, y) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\right)$$

It says it's easy to verify they are both continuous and inverse to one another.

Yet I am having troubles in showing this. The definition of continuity that it's been adopted is: a map $f$ is continuous, $f: X \to Y$, if for any subset $A$ of $X$ and for any point $x \in X$ adherent to $A$, $f(x)$ si adherent to $f(A)$.

How can I apply this definition to these maps?

Also I tried to show they are inverse to one another but when I calculate $f\circ g$ I do not get anything suitable.

**Adds**

Since $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and the same for $g$, both the compositions $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are possible.

For $f\circ g$, I associated the $x, y$ components of $g$ into $x, y$ components of $f$. For its first component I got

$$(f\circ g)(x,y)= \left(\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\vert \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \vert + \vert \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\vert},\dots\right).$$

But solving, this returns to be $\frac{x}{\vert x\vert + \vert y \vert}$ which is the same component of $f$ from which I started.

Basically I get $f\circ g= f$.

Comment: There are many equivalent definitions of continuity. A more practical here is: a map with values in $\Bbb R^2$ (or a subset thereof) is continuous iff its two components are (and the usual functions used here are continuous: $(x,y)\mapsto x,$ $(x,y)\mapsto y$, $t\mapsto t^2$, $t\ge0\mapsto\sqrt t,$ $t\ne0\mapsto1/t,$ $(u,v)\mapsto u+v,$ $(u,v)\mapsto uv$).

Comment: @AnneBauval That does help indeed! I'm hence able to prove $f, g$ are continuous maps, thank you!

Comment: Can you please include your (attempt of) calculation for $f\circ g?$ (This will help us to help you.)

Comment: The proof that the functions are inverses of each other is straightforward. We can't help you to find where your proof went wrong if you don't show your calculations.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, I'll add my work!

Comment: @AnneBauval Added!

Comment: 1) To check that "both compositions are possible", there remains work. Actually you must check that $f$ really sends $S^1$ into $Q$ and $g$ really sends $Q$ into $S^1.$ 2) Your 1st component of $f\circ g$ is correct but can be simplified further: since $(x,y)\in Q$ in this context (to be allowed to apply $g$ to it), $\frac{x}{\vert x\vert + \vert y \vert}=x.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Wouldn't be sufficient to have $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ (with the obvious cut of the origin) to ensure that both $f(g)$ and $g(f)$ are computable? 

Also thank you, for with the last part of your comment I indeed obtain $x$ with is what I shall get when verifying the two function are each other inverse (I have to finish the work though)

Comment: 1) Yes it would be sufficient to compose them but this is not the way $f,g$ are defined, and (as you already noticed) they are mutual inverses only whith that definition (i.e. domains and ranges $Q,S^1$). Btw, write $f\circ g,$ not $f(g).$ So, you still have to check the point 1) of my previous comment. 2) Fine.

Comment: P.S. Reading Pierre's answer below, I realized that in my advice to check that "point 1)", I forgot to say that you must of course first check that $f,g$ are well-defined on their respective domains.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103660)

Answer (score 1):

You can check continuity of the maps by using Heine's definition of continuity, since there is no indetermination. Note that $|x|+|y| \ne 0$ in the first case and $x^2+y^2 \ne 0$ in the second.

Take $(x,y) \in Q$, i.e. such that $|x|+|y|=1$, and compute $f(g(x,y)):$

$$
f(g(x,y)) = \left( \dfrac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}},\dfrac{\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}} \right) = \left(\dfrac{x}{|x|+|y|}, \dfrac{y}{|x|+|y|} \right) = (x,y)
 $$

Conversely, taking $(x,y)\in S^1$, i.e. such that $x^2+y^2=1$, you also easliy see that $g(f(x,y)) = (x,y)$.

Comment: @Numb3rs Nothing new compared to the comments above, except the reference to "Heine's definition of continuity", which is [sequential continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Sequences_and_nets), and is equivalent to continuity because your domains are metric spaces. This is useless here since you were already " able to prove $f,g$
 are continuous maps" but may serve in other circumstances.

Comment: @AnneBauval I interrupted editing for a few hours and did not actually read the comments before I posted. I agree that this does not add to comments, but I also think it is useful to have a localized answer, not fragmented through comments. If any of the comments' authors posts an answer, I will delete this one.